# Time in One cell, how to create a formula in one column for time minus respective rows

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I have a running timer in cell `E3`. In column Q starting at row 5 and going down, I want to have a difference equation of the running time and the time as input into column O via a clickable cell. This essential will give it a look of a stop watch. The equation for one cell is simple enough `=SUM(E3-O5)`. What I am asking is how can I copy this formula through the entire column Q? If I drag the box in the right corner it changes `E3` to each respective E cell below (i.e. `=SUM(E4-O6)`. is there a way to not have to manually go to 1000 cells and manually input `E3` in the formula? Is there a macro I can create to do this using the VBA?

Also I am trying to do some conditional formatting in column Q as well and can't get it to work. I want the cell to be green from 0 to 45 mins. Yellow from 45 to 90 mins and red from 90 mins on. I have the cells formatted in 13:30:00 (hh:nn:ss), I have tried a few different formulas I've found on line, but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: Use the dollar sign to "lock" the cell in the formula. So use `=SUM($E$3-O5)`. Then when you grab the right corner and drag it down, the E3 cell will remain E3, and only the O5 reference will change.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @PeterT you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the OP may do so too.. /(^_^)

Comment: [······](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295912/which-option-shall-i-use-to-close-questions-with-answers-in-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Use the dollar sign to "lock" the cell in the formula. So use `=SUM($E$3-O5)`. Then when you grab the right corner and drag it down, the `E3` cell will remain `E3`, and only the `O5` reference will change.

This type of cell referencing is called "standard reference" or "A1 reference". Some good resources for better understanding are [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) and [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/functions/cell-references.html).

Another type of cell reference is called "R1C1" and can be very useful as well. Some good resources for better understanding are [here](http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/excel_r1c1.htm) and [this one](https://code.adonline.id.au/combining-r1c1-and-a1-cell-referencing/)